# C bit manipulation

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have to accomplish bit manipulation.

My task is to iterate through many one byte values, and pull out certain amount of bits from each byte (sometimes odd, sometimes even) and be able to combine all those together. Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Here's a better explanation. My goal is to allow me to take certain bits from one byte and combine them with bits from another byte.

So for example, combine the first 3 bits from 0xE1, with the last 5 bits from 0xA1.

Comment: Copy the seven first bits of what to where? And why do you mention "stdio"? That only have to do with input and output (like the `printf` or `scanf` functions), it has nothing to do with bit manipulations. Can you perhaps elaborate a little? Like telling us some specific input, and showing us what the output should be (and what the output currently is)? And of course try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you currently have and show us?

Comment: @Kevin That's wrong.

Comment: @Kevin ah, okay that makes sense. DO you have any sort of idea for how I would combine like say 7 bits from 1 byte, and 1 bit from another? if that makes sense.. like if I want the first 5 bits from 0xAE and then the last 3 bits from 0XE1

Comment: @JoeCaraccio we are not a tutoring site. Bit-ops are explained in every good C book or a lot of online sites, including SO.

Comment: i updated what I was trying to figure out how to do, if you don't want to help me thats fine @Olaf

Comment: `c = (0xE1u & 0x07u) | (0xA1u & 0xF8u);`

Comment: `(a & 0xE0) | (b & 0x1F)` will get the most significant 3-bits of `a` and least significant 5-bits of `b`.

Comment: @JoeCaraccio What do you call "first" bits? Standard names are "least-significant" and "most-significant".

Comment: Thanks everyone. that is basically what I was trying to accomplish

Comment: @anatolyg didn't realize that.. I'll refer to them like that in the future

Comment: @kevin , nevermind, that works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracting bits from integral values can be done with the bitwise *and* and *shift* operations.

```
unsigned int c = 23;

c & 0xF  // extract the lowest 4 bits, 0xF is binary 1111
c & 0x7F // extract the lowest 7 bits, 0x7F is binary 1111111
(c >> 4) & 0x3 // extract 2 bits starting at bit 4 (0 indexed).
```